# ios 5 UIWebView show rows from UITableView

Tags: uitableview, ios5, uiwebview

this week i started learning ios coding but i'm getting a strange error
i have made a little script witch have on main page a list of names made with `UITableView` and when someone select a row it's open the relative url, but when load the webpage something goes wrong
the webpage have rows like 'UITableView'.

did u know why it's generate that kind of error?

that is what it's generate;

[image: that is an exemple]

**UPDATE**
i have re-writed my app but the proble is still present, i don't understand why show rows on webpage

in the rootviewcontroller.m i call the WebPage class

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  NSDictionary *Game = [[self.Sections valueForKey:[[[self.Sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]; //svanisce il blu 

NSLog(@"%@", [[self.Games objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] objectForKey:@"Url"]); // funge

WebPage *newWeb = [[WebPage alloc] init];

newWeb.theUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[Game objectForKey:@"Url"]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:newWeb animated:YES];


}
```

that is WebPage.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WebPage : UITableViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {

    UIWebView *webView;
    NSURL *theUrl;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURL *theUrl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

and that is WebPage.m

```
#import "WebPage.h"

@implementation WebPage

@synthesize theUrl;
@synthesize webView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];

    webView.delegate = self;

    webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theUrl]];

    [self.view addSubview:webView];

}

@end
```

Comment: Show your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, how you start the webview.

Comment: Yeah, please update with your code so we can suggest revisions.

Comment: And `web` is what class? For the tableview, have you set special drawing options?

Comment: i've modified my post adding all info about that problem
did you know how fix it?

Comment: seem i've resolved it with
     `self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

Answer (score 0):

It is because WebPage class is derived from `UITableViewController`. Instead derive from `UIViewController`.

Eg

```
@interface WebPage : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {

    UIWebView *webView;
    NSURL *theUrl;

}
```